# How to generate uniformly new 2-D data set in a given square in python

Tags: python

How to generate uniformly new 2-D data set (dimension (10000,2) )in a given square in python，if we already know the coordinates of the four points of the square.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy.random.uniform` and specify the min and max values of each dimension.

```py
import numpy as np
data = np.random.uniform((min_d0, min_d1), (max_d0, max_d1), (10000, 2))
```

You can check the documentation here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html